# Make a Custom developed component Search engine Fiendly

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5, joomla-sef-urls, joomla-component

I am wait to get enough knowledge on how to make SEF(Search Engine Friendly) URLs for my custom component before starting to code in JOOMLA

I got an idea on how to make it from here http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

but not have a clear idea

if my component is something like 'com_exams' & the url
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_exams

If I have a page I want to route through this 'JRoute' - like this below
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_exams&examid=psc&status=1
to
http://www.example.com/exams/psc/1

how should I do, and where should I place the code to get this done

Please let me know, thanks in advance

-rahul

Comment: Maybe the sample component in this link can help you: http://joomlaprogrammingbook.com/component/content/article/9-uncategorised/76-download-code-samples-for-each-chapter.html

Answer (score 1):

The code to handle the URLs goes in the component's router.php. The page you linked has everything you need, specifically here - http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component#The_Component_Router